# Overiding FOSUserBundle Register Form

Tags: php, html, forms, symfony, fosuserbundle

I know this question is asked on and on, but i just can't find any simple answer. I'm currently trying out FosUserBundle which is pretty nice, but i have a very basic and simple front-end problems :

- i **did** manage to customize the rendering of the *login* form by creating my custom `app/Ressources/FOSUserBundle/views/Security/login.html` and copying this :

{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

```
{% block title %}Site title{% endblock %}
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}
{% block title %}Site title{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
    {# {% block fos_user_content %}{% endblock %} #}

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">

    {% if error %}
        <div>{{ error|trans }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />

    {#     <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username" name="_username">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
     #}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">{{ 'security.login.username'|trans }}</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" required="required" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">{{ 'security.login.password'|trans }}</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password" name="_password" required="required" />
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox">
        <label >
            <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" value="on"> {{ 'security.login.remember_me'|trans }}
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="{{ 'security.login.submit'|trans }}" />
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

- however, i just can't get to understand how this works just to overide the **style** of the registration form, so i can use it inside my ::base.html.twig and have a nice good-looking form.

I do not want to add whatever field to the form, juste *display* it differently, i don't understand why it isn't as simple as for the login form...

Anyone can help ? The docs just don't answer this question (the trick for the login form is already hard to understand in the docs) at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got to understand the easiest way to do this is to **create** a UserBundle which will have the FOSUserBundle as parent, and then replace the `UserBundle/Ressources/views/layout.html.twig` like the [documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.md) says. I just find it heavy-coded to create a custom Bundle instead of a custom folder in views...:(

Answer (score 0):

I don't get exactly what you mean by that, do you want to override the style of base.html.twig ? you can do that with  CSS and change anything you want inside the twig.

Comment: No i want to be able to simply include the register form in my base

Answer (score 0):

You can create layout.html.twig inside app/FOSUserBundle/views this one will override the FOSUserBundle default layout.html.twig its an easier solution if that what you wanted to do, i didn't understood your problem at first i guess ! :)

Comment: Yes but it doesn't work for registration form, that's the whole problem. Works fine with login but not register